# How to add new data source in dremio

Tags: dremio

How can i add new data source type other than the currently listed source types. 
Is it possible to  add other relational database source to dremio.
Currently in dremio it's  connecting hive through metastore is it possible to connect through jdbc.

Thanks & Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is the ARP format, which provides a generic interface for all JDBC libraries.  You can see the docs, and an implementation used for SQL Lite here.

https://github.com/dremio-hub/dremio-sqllite-connector#arp-file-format